# hasAnyRole() not working with Spring Security 5.4.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, freemarker

I have changed my spring framework version from `4.1.4.RELEASE` to `5.3.6` and spring security version from `3.2.5.RELEASE` to `5.4.6`. I'm facing problem when using `<@security.authorize access=="hasAnyRole()">` instead of `<@security.authorize ifAnyGranted="">` inside HTML-tag.

I tried a lot of solutions but didn't work. Can some one help me here, Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you give some detail into what "didn't work"

Comment: @JamesGawron Actually User Role permissions are not working

Comment: Can you share more about your application configuration?